# JPQL :grouping by date

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a table with several records for each day, and each record has a column that represents the datetime.
I want to select the count of the records for each day, so I want to create in `JPQL` a query like the following one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS o GROUP BY TRUNC(o.ORDER_DATE)
```

Unfortunately, in `JPQL` there isn't a function like `TRUNC`... :(
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use cast! That will work

```
@Query("select new DBClass(COUNT(c.field1) as count,cast(c.created as date)) from Table c GROUP BY cast(c.created as date)")
```

Comment: note that `cast` and `date` have to be lowercase, since it's handled by JPA, it's not SQL here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is it works, but did you use method function?
it will be something like

```
Expression<Date> truncExpr = cb.function("TRUNC",Date.class,orders.get("orderDate"),"MM");
criteria.groupBy(truncExpr);
```

Comment: I'm trying soon your suggestion, then I'll tell you if it works.

Comment: Im sorry i realized i told you how to do it in jpa not jpql

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate when interpreting JPQL queries understands any of the functions it knows about.  If the Dialect you are using understands TRUNC, you will be fine.  If not, create a custom dialect to register that TRUNC function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should to the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS o GROUP BY FUNC('TRUNC', o.ORDER_DATE)
```